# Use React Native module as View Layout in android application

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working with React Native and I've got an issue when I integrate React Native module into android application. As React Native guide page, we can add RN module to Activity in android via this snippet:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
    // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactNativeApp", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}
```

But I only wanna assign RN module to a specification view : e.g Frame Layout so that I wrote:

```
    public class PlaceholderContent extends FrameLayout {

        private Context mContext;
        private Application mApplication;


        public PlaceholderContent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Application application) {
            super(context);
            mContext = context;
            mApplication = application;
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            ReactRootView contentView = new ReactRootView(mContext);
            ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

            mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                    .setApplication(mApplication)
                    .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                    .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                    .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                    .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                    .build();

           contentView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactApp", null);
           this.addView(contentView);
       //LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_placeholder_content, this, true);

    //        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_container);
    //        container.addView(contentView, -1, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(5000, 5000));
    //        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).cloneInContext(contentView.getContext());
      }  }
```

I have two questions:

1. First, my above code snippet is correct or not?
2. If it is correct, I create my own component (`MyReactApp`) but when app running , screen is displaying that it is default RN app as shown on following picture. So, how to display correctly my RN view in android?

[image: screen when app running]

Thanks every one, sorry for my E and my first time to ask in here.